# Email being cleared from Member on logout

Tags: php, silverstripe

I've built a platform around the SilverStripe framework (3.6) and have found an oddity for one user case that I can't seem to replicate. When the user signs out, their email is cleared from the DB. The member still exists and if I write back in their email address in the admin, it goes back to normal.

I've added onBeforeWrite() to Member extension and have captured a stack trace and object before it is written. The Member object write does not set the email, which I assume when it gets to writing it, clears it. At that time I've also done a stack trace however it's mostly core framework files:

```
[{
    "file": "\/framework\/core\/Object.php",
    "line": 1060,
    "function": "onBeforeWrite",
    "class": "PlatformMemberExtension",
    "object": {
        "class": "PlatformMemberExtension"
    },
    "type": "->",
    "args": [null, null, null, null, null, null, null]
}, {
    "file": "\/framework\/model\/DataObject.php",
    "line": 1105,
    "function": "extend",
    "class": "Object",
    "object": {
        "destroyed": false,
        "class": "Member"
    },
    "type": "->",
    "args": ["onBeforeWrite", null]
}, {
    "file": "\/framework\/security\/Member.php",
    "line": 976,
    "function": "onBeforeWrite",
    "class": "DataObject",
    "object": {
        "destroyed": false,
        "class": "Member"
    },
    "type": "->",
    "args": []
}, {
    "file": "\/framework\/model\/DataObject.php",
    "line": 1220,
    "function": "onBeforeWrite",
    "class": "Member",
    "object": {
        "destroyed": false,
        "class": "Member"
    },
    "type": "->",
    "args": []
}, {
    "file": "\/framework\/model\/DataObject.php",
    "line": 1372,
    "function": "preWrite",
    "class": "DataObject",
    "object": {
        "destroyed": false,
        "class": "Member"
    },
    "type": "->",
    "args": []
}, {
    "file": "\/framework\/security\/Member.php",
    "line": 655,
    "function": "write",
    "class": "DataObject",
    "object": {
        "destroyed": false,
        "class": "Member"
    },
    "type": "->",
    "args": []
}, {
    "file": "\/framework\/security\/Security.php",
    "line": 410,
    "function": "logOut",
    "class": "Member",
    "object": {
        "destroyed": false,
        "class": "Member"
    },
    "type": "->",
    "args": []
}, {
    "file": "\/framework\/control\/RequestHandler.php",
    "line": 288,
    "function": "logout",
    "class": "Security",
    "object": {
        "class": "PlatformSecurity"
    },
    "type": "->",
    "args": [{}]
}, {
    "file": "\/framework\/control\/Controller.php",
    "line": 202,
    "function": "handleAction",
    "class": "RequestHandler",
    "object": {
        "class": "PlatformSecurity"
    },
    "type": "->",
    "args": [{}, "logout"]
}, {
    "file": "\/framework\/control\/RequestHandler.php",
    "line": 200,
    "function": "handleAction",
    "class": "Controller",
    "object": {
        "class": "PlatformSecurity"
    },
    "type": "->",
    "args": [{}, "logout"]
}, {
    "file": "\/framework\/control\/Controller.php",
    "line": 158,
    "function": "handleRequest",
    "class": "RequestHandler",
    "object": {
        "class": "PlatformSecurity"
    },
    "type": "->",
    "args": [{}, {}]
}, {
    "file": "\/framework\/control\/Director.php",
    "line": 385,
    "function": "handleRequest",
    "class": "Controller",
    "object": {
        "class": "PlatformSecurity"
    },
    "type": "->",
    "args": [{}, {}]
}, {
    "file": "\/framework\/control\/Director.php",
    "line": 149,
    "function": "handleRequest",
    "class": "Director",
    "type": "::",
    "args": [{}, {}, {}]
}, {
    "file": "\/framework\/main.php",
    "line": 191,
    "function": "direct",
    "class": "Director",
    "type": "::",
    "args": ["\/Security\/logout", {}]
}]
```

Of the files that are in my code (overriding core functionality) none of them override the functions this is calling, nor set the email.

Is there some other debugging I can do or something in my stack trace that could lead me to the problem?

Comment: In your `onBeforeWrite()` method you have to call `parent::onBeforeWrite()`. If you miss this nothing will be written at all.

Comment: @wmk it's there, the problem existed before I added `onBeforeWrite()` and only happens for this one person (so far).